# Issue with box-sizing:border-box and Contempo theme

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner blogger. I am using Contempo theme and came across an issue with box-sizing:border-box. I have solved the problem by systematically deleting sections of the CSS until I found the problem code.

I am wondering if anyone can explain why this problem occurred. I had added some grids to a couple to posts using examples found at https://gridbyexample.com. Not really understanding the CSS I copied it into the top of the post using

```
<style type="text/css">.
```

The grids included the following:

```
*, 
*:before, 
*:after { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

This caused the share icons not to display, see image below.  Will other problems occur now that I have deleted the above code?
Thanks
[Link to images - first image is the result of the above code, second is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDqBo.png)

Comment: If you want to be safe about the possibility of other sections using that CSS, just make a specific rule for the icons. Give them a class, like `.icons` and override the box-sizing for just those elements `.icons:before, .icons:after {box-sizing: initial;}`

Comment: Actually, the icons are defined in the template and I don't have enough knowledge to alter the template but I could use this idea for the grid definitions so that it doesn't effect the icons. Thanks.